Need help on setting up Coveo query pipelines and search hub for multiple search interfaces
We are using Coveo Platform for our XM Cloud project and there is a need to implement 3 search experiences on the website.

Global Site Search
Blogs Search - we have a separate Sitecore page template for this content type
Customer Search - we have a separate Sitecore page template for this content type

We are using Coveo atomic components to perform a search and show the results, To achieve this we wanted to create 3 search interfaces and pass the API token and Org ID, but the problem we have here is, how do we pass a parameter to Coveo to get specific set of content type for Blogs Search Component and Customer Search Component
Thank you.
Siva

You can create three separate pipelines, each for a different interface, and apply filters in the advanced section of the query pipeline based on your search criteria. For example, in your case, Global, Blog, Customer.

When you initialize the interface in your code with the organization ID and API token, add the corresponding pipeline name.
await searchInterface.initialize({
            accessToken: "xxxxxxx",
            organizationId: "yyyyyy",
            organizationEndpoints: await searchInterface.getOrganizationEndpoints('xxxxx'),
            search: {
                pipeline: "Your created pipeline name"
            }
        });

Alternatively, you can pass the pipeline in the component itself
<atomic-search-interface pipeline='your pipeline name' searchHub='Blog'></atomic-search-interface>

Hope this helps!
